# C# Activator.CreateInstance from folder - subnamespace

Tags: c#, activator

Hello I have a problem accessing classes which I have in folders within the projects.

I have project and two folders in which I have classes with the same name.

```
Parent namespace is - textboxes

In first folder namespace is - textboxes.folder1
In second folder namespace is - textboxes.folder2
```

They have different namespaces

```
folder1/
    class1
    class2
    class3

folder2/
    class1
    class2
    class3
```

I want to use it like that.

```
string current_type = "class2";

object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(object), current_type);
```

Could you please help me how to specify which class will the CreateInstance call?

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SomeNameSpace.class1))`

Comment: @Magnus wonderful :), it works